# Had been/ was -- what would be a better choice to go with in the given context?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

I **was** out of committing any crimes for quite some time until a few days ago when I committed a felony.

I **had been** out of committing any crimes for quite some time until a few days ago when I committed a felony.

Which would be a better choice to go with here, was or had been?
What difference does it make meaning wise?
And when I say "Until a few days ago", I mean a few days ago from today/now, and not sometime in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect ("had been") would normally be used in that situation since you're talking about a condition that existed prior to an event in the past.

Not directly related to your question, but "out of committing any crimes" doesn't sound natural to me. I've been trying to think of a better way to say that and haven't come up with anything that I'm happy with. Maybe someone else will have an idea.